# Inject a form_for @model from a js.erb file?

Tags: jquery, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, form-for

I am trying to figure out how to inject Rails 'form_for' helpers from a js.erb file that is called using ajax (:remote => true). 
I am dynamically bringing up information about bands that a user searches for and I want to give them the option to save the names of their bands to a database. The only way I know to do that is to inject a 'form_for' to my model onto the page. When the user clicks the 'submit' element, it will post to the 'create' action in my controller. 
Any advice would help especially if this is not a good way to accomplish what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write your form code in an ordinary `.html.erb` partial. Then in your `.js.erb` file you can render it just like you would any partial in ERB, but with `escape_javascript`, a.k.a. `j` e.g.:

```
$("#some-element").html(
  "<%= j render :partial => 'your/partial' %>"
);
```

Comment: Hey thanks that worked! Can you explain why I can't put the content in the partial directly in the jquery injection line?

Comment: You can if you want, I just broke it into a few lines for readability.